# Apache Maven installation in windows 8

Tags: windows, maven-3

I followed steps mentioned in this link http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Whenever I type mvn --version in cmd.
I got 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

But when I opened cmd with "Run as a administrator" it worked.

OS: windows 8

How can I run mvn for any user on windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable M2 as System variable instead of User variable.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about), started as an Administrator, and put these variables into my System path, and this problem went away.

For some reason, when I added the the JDK, JRE, and Maven bin folders to my Path through the Windows utility, it didn't work. Rapid Environment Editor told me that the variables were not valid or I did not have access to them. Windows 8 seems to be really picky about administrator rights and I guess they didn't think that through very well.

Just be sure to start Rapid Environment Editor as an administrator, and re-open your command windows when you save your changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had to move the installation directory of Maven into C:\Users*your_username*, so that Maven no longer required admin permissions.  The PATH variables started working after that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `MAVEN`/`M2` and `MAVEN_HOME`/`M2_HOME` variables in the environment variables in windows 8, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chinese version so that i'm not sure what's these word in english version.

click right button on "My computer" 
click last item on list
click "Advanced system setting" at left side
"Evironment Variable"
append maven's bin directory into system's environment variables *path*

after all, try linux

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:
Add maven directory to the path in systems variable.
don't add anything in user variable and no need to add any variable.

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem; The bins or files from path for M2_home and Java_home need to be found in a directory where the user has full control permission. Change the security permission settings of the user through the administrator by right click on the order, go to properties->security tab and check the Full control box for "authenticated user" and "user".