# Apache Maven Installation on Windows 8 64-bit machine

Tags: windows, maven, environment-variables

I am trying to install Apache Maven version 3.2.3 on my Windows 8 machine. I have followed the steps given in 
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

After doing everything listed in there, I still find Maven is not installed well. When i type "mvn --version" in my command propmt, it says "'mvn' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

I have tried all the alternatives given in [Apache Maven installation in windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731610/apache-maven-installation-in-windows-8) but none of them seems to work.

Someone please help me. Please do not consider this as a repetitive question.

Comment: What is the result if you `cd` into your `<Maven installation dir>\bin` on the command line and invoke `mvn` there?

Comment: Can you post the output of the `path` command?

Comment: Thankyou for the responses. I have resolved the issue. For some reason (I dont know why) I included "C:\Windows\System32" in the path and everything worked.